# My server does not support JSON field in mysql

Tags: mysql, json, mariadb

I have developed my website with 10.3.8-MariaDB and when I deployed the website to the SiteGround server, JSON fields gave an error. JSON fields support MySQL >= 5.7, however, SiteGround's MYSQL version is 5.6 . Now, I want to run code

```
ALTER TABLE courses 
ADD slug_en VARCHAR(255) AS (JSON_DECODE(slug, '$.en'));
```

it gives me an error. How can I select JSON values or run this code in MYSQL? Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the future, you should develop with the exact same software versions that you will eventually deploy to.

Answer (score 3):

contact your server and request for updating mySQL version; MySql above versions supports json field

Comment: They offer it only in dedicated servers, and it is very expensive.

Comment: Sadly, since your MySQL database doesn't provide what you want, you will need to add an additional layer of program code to parse and generate your JSON (should be relatively easy, depending on the JSON functionality of your programming language). Or, maybe easier, get a new hosting service! The one you have does not deserve your money, I think.